# How to use full text search feature of H2 database in java?

Tags: java, database, indexing, h2

Anybody please explain how to use the Full-Text search for H2 Embedded Database with the help of java program.

executing "SELECT * FROM FT_SEARCH_DATA('word', 0, 0)" is returning a select query string. Do i need to execute this one again to get the final result?

Comment: The example in the tutorial seems pretty clear to me. Have you tried following it? If not, do so. If so, edit your question to explain what your specific problem is. At the moment, your question reads like "I am too lazy and/or stupid to follow the tutorial", which does not encourage people to answer.

Comment: Low voter turnout is disappointing, too.

Comment: I don't understand the 'QUERY: "PUBLIC"."TEST" WHERE "ID"=1'

Comment: From the tutorial, "`PUBLIC` is the schema name, `TEST` is the table name."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Java program that uses the H2 fulltext index is [the unit test program](http://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/browse/trunk/h2/src/test/org/h2/test/db/TestFullText.java). An example from there:

```
    Connection conn = ...
    Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
    stat.execute("CREATE ALIAS IF NOT EXISTS FT_INIT FOR \"org.h2.fulltext.FullText.init\"");
    stat.execute("CALL FT_INIT()");
    FullText.setIgnoreList(conn, "to,this");
    FullText.setWhitespaceChars(conn, " ,.-");
    stat.execute("CREATE TABLE TEST(ID INT PRIMARY KEY, NAME VARCHAR)");
    stat.execute("INSERT INTO TEST VALUES(1, 'Welcome to this world, One_Word')");
    stat.execute("CALL FT_CREATE_INDEX('PUBLIC', 'TEST', NULL)");
    ResultSet rs;
    rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM FT_SEARCH('Welcome', 0, 0)");
    assertTrue(rs.next());
    assertEquals("QUERY", rs.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(1));
    assertEquals("SCORE", rs.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(2));
    assertEquals("\"PUBLIC\".\"TEST\" WHERE \"ID\"=1", rs.getString(1));
    assertEquals("1.0", rs.getString(2));
    rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM FT_SEARCH_DATA('One', 0, 0)");
    assertFalse(rs.next());
    rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM FT_SEARCH_DATA('One_Word', 0, 0)");
    assertTrue(rs.next());
    rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM FT_SEARCH_DATA('Welcome', 0, 0)");
    assertTrue(rs.next());
```

There is also a [SQL script example](http://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/browse/trunk/h2/src/test/org/h2/samples/fullTextSearch.sql). And maybe your are interested in the [Javadocs for the FullText class](http://h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/fulltext/FullText.html) - this will explain what `FT_SEARCH_DATA` / `searchData` returns.

Comment: +1 I often check `src/test/org/h2/samples` for insights, but I'll start checking `src/test/org/h2/test`, too.

Comment: Thanks thomas. but i have a question stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM FT_SEARCH_DATA('One', 0, 0)") is again returning a query without select clause do i have to re-execute this query again to get the final result that includes the word 'one'. My second question is how could i use the "like %one%" in SELECT * FROM FT_SEARCH_DATA.

Comment: Yes you have to execute the query to get the final result. FT_SEARCH_DATA only returns a pointer to the real data. Returning the final result would be very problematic if the final result is a large document.