# Perform a fulltext search in H2 database using JPA (Eclipselink)

Tags: java, jpa, full-text-search, eclipselink, h2

In my project I use embedded H2 database and JPA (eclipselink).
I need to make such a query: `SELECT * FROM products WHERE title like '%the_name%'`
The leading % eliminates using indexes, so H2 performs a full table scan. I have to increase the performance of that query. The possible solution I've found is creating a fulltext index on that column and making a fulltext search.
The database must be created with these params:

```
properties.put("eclipselink.ddl-generation", "create-tables");
properties.put("eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode", "database");
```

How can this be done using JPA and H2? How to make that index and query from JPA? Please give an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute your own DDL to create the fulltext index, either through your own script, or through JPA when your app starts up, such as using a SessionCustomizer or SessionEvent.

To call the fulltext function you can use the JPQL FUNC or FUNCTION operator.

See,
[How to use full text search feature of H2 database in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611764/how-to-use-full-text-search-in-h2)